# .net IIS Classic app pool injecting bytes into my image

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have an old asp.net web application running in classic mode in IIS which runs code similar to the reproduction case below. It seems that every time the `Write` method is called I get extra few bytes injected (hex string of size of bytes written followed by CR and NL) into my output stream before the data is written.

default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        string str1 = ResolveUrl("~/image.jpg");
        string str2 = this.Server.MapPath(str1);

        string str = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Path.GetFileName(str2), Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", "%20");
        this.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + str);
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(str2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            this.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1));
            long lengthLeft = stream.Length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            while (lengthLeft > 0L && this.Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                int count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);
                this.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                this.Response.Flush();
                lengthLeft -= (long)count;
            }
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

place any `image.jpg` in the directory and make the directory a virtual application in iis.

So far this is only happening on one server (the qa environment for this application), Server 2008 R2 Standard all Windows Update patches applied.

Does anyone know why `Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count)` would write `string.Format("{0:x}\r\n", count)` to the output stream before the contents of the buffer?

edit: resolution:

The problem doesn't happen on Server 2016 in IIS classic mode and also the application appears to be functional in integrated pipeline mode which also doesn't produce the issue. While I'd still like to know why this regression occurred, the matter is no longer pressing since we have 2 workarounds and it appears unlikely to impact us in production.

Comment: Sounds like somehow your code calls to https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpWriter.cs,fddccfb26dbb7001,references . If possible, debugging the reference code would give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing the buffer after every write is possibly inserting the suspect return and NewLine characters. You do not need to flush the buffer after every write, and in fact it is frowned upon in many situations. Remove the flush and retest.

Comment: Commenting out the flush does fix the issue, but I cannot do that in the actual code. The reproduction case above was based on the decompiled sources of a product we do not have the ability to rebuild.

Comment: You might have to follow up file output with a regex to take out new lines and return characters. It’s not an ideal solution, but if you don’t have access to the source to be able to fix it properly it might be the only way

Comment: We are switching the qa environment to server 2016 which does not reproduce the issue and matches the production environment that went live last month.